# Django how to filter objects in many to many field, not the original queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

i'm trying to filter objects in a manytomany field of a queryset and am having difficulty, most other posts seemed to address filtering the queryset based on the contents of the manytomany field whereas i need to filter the ManyToMany field itself.

Models:

```
class IngredientsUserNeeds(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
   drinks = models.ManyToManyField(Drink)

class Drink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

In my ListAPI view, I start filtering by

```
qs = IngredientsUserNeeds.objects.all().filter(user=user)
```

But after calling this, I want to filter out drinks in each object of the qs that do not belong to a particular user like,

```
qs = qs.filter(drinks=drink_object)
```

However, this call filters the original `IngredientsUserNeeds` queryset and not the items in it's `ManyToMany` field. How can I modify my filter so that it does not filter the queryset but rather the items in each of its object's `ManyToMany` Fields?

**Edit 1**

```
    for obj in qs:
        obj.drinks = obj.drinks.all().filter(user=user)
```

I got to this point, but it unfortunately modifies the original queryset in the database. Any suggestions so that I can retain the original queryset? This is being carried out in a Django Rest Framework ListAPIView if that helps

Comment: Sorry, this is a little bit confuse. At the end of the day, you want to keep IngredientsUserNeeds instances whose drinks belong to the current user ? If it's so see my answer below

Comment: I mean that I have a query set of ingredientsuserneeds objects, and rather than filtering that query set, I want to filter the drinks many to many field of each object based on whether or not the drink's user field contains a particular user

Comment: @AlexNelson did you ever get a solution for this? I need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

something like this ?

```
qs = IngredientsUserNeeds.objects.filter(user=user,drinks__user=user)
```

Comment: thats what I originally tried, and I get a result that is the right object that I need, but it does not filter the drinks themselves. For example, say the queryset has 2 objects, each like the following: {user: 1, drinks: ['coke','sprite']} {user: 2, drinks:['pepsi','mountaindew']} and say for pepsi, the users field includes user2 but for mountaindew, the users field does not include user2. I would want my filter to return {user: 2, drinks['pepsi']} without mountaindew. Understand the example?

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I don't think that you can achieve what you want through a single django queryset. Do the query above and then that one:

    Drink.objects.filter(user=user)

and combine both results. I see no other way, but I'd be glad to learn a useful tip for that if someone else has a better idea :)

Comment: So I would filter on object.drinks.all() for each object in the original queryset? How would I get these filtered drink querysets back into the original queryset?

Comment: So I tried         elif userQuery and user.is_authenticated():
            for obj in qs:
                obj.drinks = obj.drinks.all().filter(user=user)
But it modifies the actuall queryset in the database, any way around this that you know of?